# Where does the function fopen() in C creates the file, opened in write mode?

Tags: c, fopen

Where is the directory?
i've searched for possibly all the directories but couldn't find any file related to the program

Comment: 1) Post the name used  2) Post evidence that the `fopen()` succeeded. [mcve]  IOWs, the function failed, that is why "couldn't find any file",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). If it does not maybe the call is not successfully. Check its return-code.

Comment: What is "the working directory" here?

Comment: @drac_o: the directory where you run the program from.

Answer (score 1):

`fopen()` function is used to open a file to perform operations such as reading, writing etc. In a `C program`, we declare a file pointer and use `fopen()` as below. `fopen()` function creates a new file if the mentioned file name does not exist. The directory where you run the program from

The following example shows the usage of fopen() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
   FILE * fp;

   fp = fopen ("file.txt", "w+");
   fprintf(fp, "%s %s %s %d", "We", "are", "in", 2012);

   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

Let us compile and run the above program that will create a file file.txt with the following content −

```
We are in 2012
```

Now let us see the content of the above file using the following program −

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   FILE *fp;
   int c;

   fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
   while(1) {
      c = fgetc(fp);
      if( feof(fp) ) { 
         break ;
      }
      printf("%c", c);
   }
   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

Let us compile and run the above program to produce the following result −

```
We are in 2012
```

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question.